# Material 2 changing font size in Mat-Toolbar

Tags: angular-material2

I am trying to change the font size of a text in mat-toolbar, but nothing seems to work . In the plunker example i have 2 spans 'AAA product' and 'some long description' . how do i change the font size of these elements . applying style to the span doesnt seem to take effect. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" >
  <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>

<span>AAA product  </span>
 <span class="test"></span>
<span style="font-height=10px">Some Longer description</span>

<span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
```

[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/PMo8mPpaDh4XxCwBaGzN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
<span style='font-size:333%;'>AAA product</span>
```

There's some more info on https://material.angular.io/guide/typography